# Problem building gscam on groovy armhf

Tags: gscam, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, armhf, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to build gscam fro groovy on ubuntu 12.04armhf and get a message that quite a few deps are not released. Looking at the status page http://namniart.com/repos/status/groovy.html, it shows that it is not available for GsrcP 433 and GbinParmhf 455. Apparently mine is that version. Since the package is maintained by J. Bohren and R. Toris, I would like to know if the deps problem is indeed the reason it is missing.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117276/problem-building-gscam-on-groovy-armhf/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a build of gscam available in the latest set of binary builds of Groovy for ARM. **Note that the repository *URL* and *key* have changed**: http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-01-19**:
Since this link mentions Raring, is this only for Raring or for Precise as well? I'm using Precise.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-19**:
Sorry; my initial response had the wrong link. Yes, this applies to Precise as well.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-01-22**:
Thanks. I have tried to install gscam using "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-gscam" but it still says there's no such package. "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-g" shows 14 packages, but no gscam. Neither does synaptic. Any clue what's going wrong ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-23**:
Can you confirm that you have the updated package URL ( deb http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros precise main ) in your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list ?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-01-23**:
Ok, totally forgot to update that. After updating, it can install gscam with dependencies. And can you confirm that there is a GPG error on the URL because the signature cannot be verified ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-24**:
The key has also changed. Please run: wget http://packages.namniart.com/repos/namniart.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-01-24**:
After running wget, apt-get install ros-groovy-gscam gives the warning that gscam as well as its dependencies can not be authenticated. Is this ok or not ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-24**:
I haven't had this problem on my systems. Did you pipe the output from wget into apt-key add to add the new key?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-01-24**:
Yes, but I think I have a problem. After running wget | sudo , it gets the key and waits a very long time. Then asks for pw and gives ok. When I try to install gscam, it gives the authentication warning again.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-24**:
That sounds like it's adding the key correctly. You may need to run 'apt-get update' after adding a new key.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-01-24**:
That worked. Question on the path though: according to http://wiki.ros.org/gscam, to start roscd gscam && cd bin. But this path doesn't exist. I have /opt/ros/groovy/lib/gscam and /opt/ros/groovy/share/gscam, and no bin. Did I miss something ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-24**:
That sounds like a problem with gscam and should probably be the subject of a new question.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-01-24**:
On my x86 electric, gscam works fine. On x86 groovy (installed just now) it's the same problem. So it looks like the gscam groovy build is wrong somehow.  Will ask the maintainer.